# What are the disadvantages of using services such as Firebase when compared to writing your own back-end?

Tags: database, rest, mobile, backend

I am trying to build a mobile application (Android/iOS) and the app will require a lot of back end operations.

After doing some research I noticed that several developers recommended using [MBaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_backend_as_a_service) services only if the back end operations are very simplistic however since I have little experience using these tools I had trouble understanding why they made such recommendations.

My questions are:

1. What are the limitations of using a service like [firebase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase)?
2. Why do large companies choose to build their own back ends and APIs instead of using MBaaS services?
3. Can someone please give me an example of something that can be done by building your own back end that cannot be done using a service like Firebase?

Comment: Firebase as backend => My business is the mobile App. Custom backend => my business is on the backend and I also offer a mobile app as a client to my service. Can you imagine Netflix implemented on Firebase? I can not. Can you imagine a mobile video game without backend? Yes, I guess you can. All depends on **where is your business*

Answer (score 1):

I think you can break down the down sides generally into 3 categories

1. Cost. At scale, machines in your own datacenter will generally be much cheaper to run.
2. Trust/Risk. Having another third party in the chain introduces various risks.

   - What if they go bust?
   - What if thier jurisdictions data protection laws aren't compatible with ours?
   - Are they monetising our data?
   - Are we locked in to their services?
3. Compatibility with existing infrastructure. A large company is likely to already have some existing IT infrastructure.

   - Can the hosted backend query our on site customer db to return a result?
   - Can our onsite reporting tool combine onsite and hosted data for reporting?

Obviously for a small company, with a low volume service not having to expend the upfront capital to build your own datacenter is a massive plus.

But as you scale these other issue become more important to you.

In terms of things you literaly can not do. Well I guess there are some technical things where you need stuff on premise. Say you have specific hardware. A ticket printing machine, a 3D printer etc

But its more likely to be a contractual or legal restriction.

When we signed customer X we promised to keep thier data in our audited data center/delete it unretrievabley after X days etc

The new EU data protection law says we cant put this data on russian servers without the agreement of each user.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the limitations of using a service like firebase?

Implementing your own custom solutions on top of a service can become very cumbersome as well as tailoring solutions to specific needs hard. It might force you to adhere to some of their data, performing a lot of data mangling, accepting their business rules, and so on.

> Why do large companies choose to build their own back ends and APIs instead of using MBaaS services?

Because it increases the ability to build aforementioned custom solutions in addition to the fact that you have better control and ownership of the data (the latter is typically a very important aspect to companies in general). You're not constrained by external partners but by your own ability to deliver (which for the record might not be better than the service).

> Can someone please give me an example of something that can be done by building your own back end that cannot be done using a service like Firebase?

Not really, it all depends on what you strive to achieve and what the service offers. I have never used Firebase but their feature list looks pretty good.

This is more one of those situations where the devil is in the details. If you want to track a specific event in a very specific manner at a very specific time you might be very constrained by using Firebase. If you need direct access to all the data to be able to run heavy queries, jobs or perform analyses on it you might find that you actually need to retrieve the data from Firebase in order to do it. Your ability to tailor delivery of content might be severely hampered, say that you want to cache something for a specific time on the client side through Cache-Control headers yet they do not provide it. Creating your own cache layer using something such as Memcached or Redis might not be possible at all.

As a company matures these types of actions and solutions typically become more important.

I'm not saying that Firebase cannot do these things, but the deeper one delves the more one is typically constrained by the service. This means that these services are typically excellent if you don't know enough about how to build something better suited for your application, find that they provide precise what you need or you just don't care enough about any of those things and just want to get something up and running.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the limitations of using a service like firebase?

Firebase uses a no-SQL database

Although this has advantages in terms of scaling, it has disadvantages if you’re managing large amounts of highly structured data. With a regular relational database you can write powerful queries in SQL to quickly get the data your looking for - there’s no equivalent with Firebase. Also, you could use an ORM to further simplify data handling.

> Why do large companies choose to build their own back ends and APIs
>   instead of using MBaaS services?

There are two divergent trends happening in mobile development right now. The most common one is the mobile-first approach strategy. You construct a landing page website and then build a product in iOS, if targeting the U.S. market, or Android, if targeting the European market. Then, you push a single version and develop for other markets down the line.

The other trend is the API-first approach, in which the underlying construct — the application programming interface (API) — is built first. This strategy allows the website and apps on various platforms to be built on top of the same basic conditions. If your sole target audience is iOS users, perhaps a mobile-first strategy works for you. However, the downside is this hinders quick development for future audiences, including Windows, BlackBerry, Android, and a web-app for your non-mobile users.

*you should read this -* http://nordicapis.com/why-you-should-build-apps-with-an-api-backend-baas/